# Does the 15 Strength effect apply when a PC is in their humanoid form?

Tags: dnd-5e, lycanthropy

The rules of lycanthropy on p207 of the Monster Manual state that a werewolf characters "gains a Strength of 15 if his or her score isn't already higher, and a +1 bonus to AC while in wolf or hybrid form (from natural armor)."

I interpret this to mean that the Strength bonus is always in effect, but I think it's ambiguous. Is the 15 Strength always in effect?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Correct.

Pg. 207

> **Player Characters as Lycanthropes**
> A character who becomes a lycanthrope retains his or her statistics except as specified by lycanthrope type.
>
> **Werewolf**
> Character gains a strength of 15 if his or her score isn't already higher.

There are several references to non-transformed changes in the text around lycanthropy such as:

> A werewolf is a savage predator.  In its humanoid form a werewolf has heightened senses, a fiery temper, and a tendency to eat rare meat.

As well as in the description of the curse of lycanthropy on page 206

> In its natural humanoid form, a creature cursed by lycanthropy appears as its normal self.  Over time, however, many lycanthropes acquire features suggestive of their animal form.